# "Describe all the solutions of the system in parametric vector form"

Tags: linear-algebra

So I'm trying to understand some old homework problems for a quiz and I came across a problem I left blank (probably because I didn't understand it) and I have no idea what to do with it.  The problem is as follows:

> Let A = $\begin{bmatrix}
>  -1 & -4 & 0 & -4 \\  2 & -8 & 0 & 8 \end{bmatrix}$. Describe all solutions of the system Ax = b in parametric vector form.

But they don't give you "b" so what the heck am I supposed to do here?

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is a matrix of dimension $2\times 4$ the equation $Ax=b$ asks to find a column vector 
$$ x=\left[ \begin{array}{c} x_1\\ x_2\\x_3\\x_4 \end{array} \right] $$
for each given
$$ b=\left[ \begin{array}{c} b_1\\ b_2 \end{array}\right]. $$
Thus one has to solve the system of linear equations
$$-x_1-4x_2-4x_4=b_1,\quad 2x_1-8x_2+8x_4=b_2.$$
There are only two equations and four unknowns. Hence the solutions can be expressed by
two parameters, say $s$ and $t$. One can take $x_3=s$ and $x_4=t$. Now the system is reduced to a system with two equations and two unknowns
$$-x_1-4x_2=b_1+4t,\quad 2x_1-8x_2=b_2-8t.$$
We solve it 
$$x_1=-\frac{1}{2}b_1+\frac{1}{4}b_2-4t,\quad x_2=-\frac{1}{8}b_1-\frac{1}{16}b_2. $$
The final solution is
$$ x=\left[ \begin{array}{c} -\frac{1}{2}b_1+\frac{1}{4}b_2\\ -\frac{1}{8}b_1-\frac{1}{16}b_2\\0\\0 \end{array} \right]+s\left[ \begin{array}{c} 0\\ 0\\1\\0 \end{array} \right]+t\left[ \begin{array}{c} -4\\ 0\\0\\1 \end{array} \right]. $$